# Move SQL Express 2014 database to existing SQL Server 2019 Standard Instance

Tags: sql-server-2019, sql-server-express

I have a SQL Express 2014 instance on a server with 1 database that has 1 table. I would like to move that database to an existing SQL Server 2019 Standard instance that is on a different server. The windows server version of the Express instance is 2012R2, the windows server version of the SQL Standard version is 2019, both are 64-bit.

I'm a SQL newbie. Can someone point me to a how-to guide that tells me how to move that sql express database? All I've been able to find are instructions for upgrading the SQL server, not moving a database to an existing server.

Comment: Any reason not to just manually recreate the database and table on the Standard instance, and script out the data or use a data migration tool?...how much data is there (by size and / or row count)?

Comment: I was definitely considering doing that but didn't know if it would cause a problem going from one version to another. There are only 40,575 rows in the table.

Comment: Can I just script out the database and create a new one in the standard instance using that script?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do a backup of the express database and restore it to the standard instance?